# Install windows on a second partition without creating an entry in the boot menu

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, partitioning, multi-boot

I have a PC and want to install windows on a second partition. However, when the machine boots I do not want to modify the boot menu to show two operating systems. Instead I would like to access the second operating system by booting from USB and selecting the second partition.

I have been able to create a second partition already and formatted it as NTFS.

I have windows 7 on the primary partition and want to install windows 8.1 64 on the second (hidden) partition.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: Hi This is not a work PC given to me by work, it is my own PC that i use for work,however I wanted to hide the second operating system   for security reasons.

Comment: Well it's easy to hide the partition, though I'm stuck on how to choose to boot from in via the USB.

Comment: think once I have installed the operating system without topuching the boot menu, then I just make a bootable usb/sd card and install a bootloader that allows me to select the second partition...

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to install as normal, then remove the partition you want to conceal from the boot menu. There are free boot managers that will allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to just unplug the main harddrive prior to the installation. It will not be able to alter its files or boot order. If you then boot and use the boot menu to select USB drive, it will work as expected.

Alternatively you could look into using a virtual machine and install the OS in there. That is not the same, but depending on what you want to do, it may be enough.